# Nested devise model form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested-forms

I am using devise to authenticate users, and I want to assign a location to a user at the time of signup in the same form. I am currently getting this error when submitting the form. Any ideas?

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in DeviseInvitable::RegistrationsController#create

Location(#70224765161800) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#70224763369340)

My location model

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :users, :dependent => :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :allow_destroy => true
 attr_accessible :lat, :long, :name, :street_adress
 attr_accessible :user_attributes
end
```

My user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :location
 rolify
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
 attr_accessible :role_ids, :as => :admin
 attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :location
end
```

My new.html.erb view

```
<% resource.build_location %>
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url =>       registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>

<%= f.fields_for @location do |location_form| %>
<%= location_form.text_field :name %>
<% end %>

<%= f.input :name, :autofocus => true %> 
<%= f.input :email, :required => true %>
<%= f.input :password, :required => true %>
<%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true %>

<%= f.button :submit, 'Sign up', :class => 'btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

locations_controller

```
 def new
    @location = Location.new
    @location.user.build
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @location }
    end
  end

  # GET /locations/1/edit
  def edit
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /locations
  # POST /locations.json
  def create
    @location = Location.new(params[:location])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @location.save
        format.html { redirect_to @location, notice: 'Location was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @location, status: :created, location: @location }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @location.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

users_controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    authorize! :index, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
   authorize! :update, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   if @user.update_attributes(params[:user], :as => :admin)
   redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
   redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    authorize! :destroy, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    unless user == current_user
      user.destroy
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "Can't delete yourself."
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You're are creating a `User`, so the `User` class should have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :location`. But I'm not sure it will solve the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're are creating a User, so the User class should have accepts_nested_attributes_for :location. But I'm not sure it will solve the problem...